# Synchronise Azure Active Directory with OpenLDAP - possible?

Tags: azure, ldap, openldap

we have a Sharepoint online site and an Azure Active Directory to manage our users. We also use OpenLDAP on a Linux server and I want to synchronize both of them, so everytime I make changes on the users on LDAP it synchronises these changes with Azure AD.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But your questions is a bit broad to really give a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Connect does have the concept of a generic LDAP connector, however it is not an easy to deploy approach, and requires extensive manual configuration. Microsoft recommendations are shown [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-hybrid-identity-design-considerations-tools-comparison):

> Currently there are two supported options for this. They are:
>
> You can use the generic LDAP connector and enable it outside of Azure
>   AD Connect. This is complex and requires a partner for on-boarding and
>   a premier support agreement to maintain. This option can handle both
>   single and multiple LDAP directories.
>
> You can develop your own solution for moving objects from LDAP to
>   Active Directory. Then synchronize the objects with Azure AD Connect.
>   MIM or FIM could be used as a possible solution for moving the
>   objects.